# deleted photos still take up storage

Tags: iphone, photos, storage, space

I have deleted all my pics including from recently deleted and i have 45GB in icloud but still my photos are taking up a lot of space even though there is nothing in the photo album. Please help urgent issue!!

Comment: Please elaborate. Are you talking only about the iCloud? How do you know they're still taking the space? If you're talking about disk space, have you tried to empty the Trash?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for a long time with my 16gb iPhone. After a lot of looking I discovered iExplore and this tip:

http://iexplorer-support.macroplant.com/customer/portal/articles/1325738-how-to-delete-all-photos-from-an-iphone-or-ipad

Essentially, Photos caches lots of files and due iOS bugs, the caches don't always get cleared up.

I used the solution on the above page and cleared up 2GB of space.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved my problem using iExplorer (mentioned by @billyork23). In my case, it is the thumbnail data of old photos. You can locate it under:

Media/PhotoData/Thumbnails

and delete all .ithumb files. It saves me 1.5GB.

P.S. The iExplorer does not require jailbreak or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but theres a few things to consider. first doing a reboot might help. second its possible a app have alot of photos for the graphics of the app. also when you delete a file (i.e. pictures) it just marks it as free space and its possible something isnt considering it as free space. i might be wrong i am not completely sure.

Comment: "second its possible a app have alot of photos for the graphics of the app." That's not how that works. App assets (including photos or images) are stored in the app bundle for that app, and are not reported as photos under Usage.

Comment: oh, i am sorry. i am a android user and didnt know that

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using the google photos app, as you will have unlimited storage if you were to use the "High Quality" Image choice. And then the app will ask you if you would like to free up device storage, and accept. That, personally is the best option for me.

Comment: This doesn't address the user's issue of photos that were already deleted continuing to take up space.

Comment: Apple insist on perfecting their users from themselves yet creates bugs in their software that infuriates their customers. Google photos is at least more transparent in their features and their features at least work correctly. I paid for iCloud storage at a 2x premium compared to google drive, yet their features don't work with iCloud and iPhone.